# how to do constraint based loading in informatica for more than one source?

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I am trying to use constraint based loading in informatica to load data from more than one source to target on the basis of parent child relation. How can i use more than one source files to achieve the same ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide from-scratch coding service here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Functionality of constraint base load is to load primary key target first and then the foreign key target for which source data need to be in de normalized format where in row should columns for primary key target and foreign target.

In your senario if your files are header and detail then join them using joiner and populate to targets